# Specifying a range of columns in a lambda function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let me start with a minimum working example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
test = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([[45, .25, .25, .25, .25], 
                                   [37, .75, .25, 0.0, 0.0], 
                                   [29, 1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
                                   [70, .25, 0.0, 0.0, .57]]), 
                    index=[1, 2, 3, 4], 
                    columns=['Unneeded', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

Thus we have the following data frame in pandas:

```
>>> test
   Unneeded     A     B     C     D
1      45.0  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25
2      37.0  0.75  0.25  0.00  0.00
3      29.0  1.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
4      70.0  0.25  0.00  0.00  0.57
```

The variables `A` through `D` represent shares of something, which is why row-wise they add to one. I want to calculate a new variable that holds the entropy index for each row. The entropy index is the sum over x=A,B,C,D of the following function:

```
lambda x: x * math.log(1.0/x, 2) if x > 0 else 0
```

I know that I can do simple column generation in a pandas data frame by syntax like this:

```
test['sum_ab'] = test['A'] + test['B']
```

I also know that I can generate columns with more complicated transformations using lambda functions:

```
test['dub_a'] = test.A.apply(lambda x: x * 2) # or test['A'].apply(...
```

I also know that you can use lambda functions with map() to apply the function to each item in the list. So my thinking is to generate a new variable by applying the necessary lambda function to each item in those four columns, then sum the items in the resulting list. Hence I've tried the following syntax:

```
test['entropy'] = sum(list(map(lambda x: x * math.log(1.0/x, 2) \
    if x > 0 else 0, LIST)))
```

**...but here my troubles begin.** I've just written `LIST` there because I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to make a list out of these column names such that this function will work. I know that the basic idea itself works:

```
>>> list_1 = [.25, .25, .25, .25]
>>> entropy_1 = sum(list(map(lambda x: x * math.log(1.0/x, 2) \
        if x > 0 else 0, list_1)))
>>> entropy_1
2.0
```

I just can't figure out how to tell it to do this to the elements of the columns in a pandas data frame.

Everything I've read on pandas so far, when it comes to selecting columns, seems to assume you're subsetting the data frame. But that's not what I want to do here. This type of column creation implicitly works on every row in the column at once; thus you don't specify any (or all) rows when you write something like `test['sum_ab'] = test['A'] + test['B']`. It seems like I should be able to do something like that here: that I should be able to specify `test[['A':'D']]` or the like as my `LIST`. But I've come up goose eggs so far.

Usually when I get this close to a solution and then can't find any related questions, it's a sign that I'm on fundamentally the wrong track. Such may be the case here, but if anyone has ideas about how I might proceed, I'd be grateful.

P.S.: I included the `Unneeded` column to emphasize that I need to specify some, not all, the columns in the data frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to `apply`, you can use vectorized operations.

```
relevant = test[['A','B','C','D']]
entropy = (relevant * (np.log2(1) - np.log2(relevant))).fillna(0).sum(1)
```

First, compute a frame where each entry is of the form `x * np.log2(1/x)` or `0`. Then, sum across rows to get the answer.

Comment: I see--and then append that column back to the original data frame. Thank you, this is quite helpful. Am I correct to think that this would be considerably faster at scale than `apply`?

Comment: I would guess that this would beat apply in terms of speed. Also, note that creating a list for each row leads to additional memory overhead.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I am slowly, painfully moving into python from years of doing data analysis in Stata, and almost every day I discover a bad habit that programming in the latter has formed in me. For example, in Stata you always work within what amounts to a single data frame, so I hadn't thought about how subsetting would be more efficient.